# Series and polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, convergence-divergence

Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\geq 2$ such that any integer is not a root of $p$, i.e, $p(n)\neq 0\;\forall\,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Is it true that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}<\infty$$

for any polynomial $p$ satisfying the above conditions and with real coefficients? If not, what about

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}?$$

Comment: I have written an Edit to my answer making the link with complex function theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they both converge. If the polynomial is of degree $\geq 2$ then, for $|n|$ large enough, we have

$$
-\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\frac{1}{p(n)}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$

Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, then also $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p(n)}$ must converge (absolutely) by the comparison test (and same for the series over $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: No, I am sorry, you have not $-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}\leq\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ because in the proof, you have to drop a certain number of terms. Another even simpler reason explaining that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}$ can take any real value is that you can multiply one of its values by any real you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is always convergence.

Consider the second degree case (the same demonstration could be given for any degree $>2$).

We can restrict our attention as well to the part with positive indices:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{an^2+bn+c}$$

(the other part can be treated in the same way).
We may also assume that $a>0$ (otherwise we take the opposite of the series).

As

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ \frac{an^2+bn+c}{(a/2)n^2} = 2$$

we can say that, there exists a $n_0$ such that :

$$\text{for any} \ n>n_0, \ \ \frac{an^2+bn+c}{(a/2)n^2} > 1$$

i.e.,

$$\text{for} \ n>n_0, \ an^2+bn+c \ > \ \frac{a}{2}n^2 \ > \ 0$$

Thus

$$0<\sum_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{an^2+bn+c}<\frac{2}{a}\sum_{n=n_0+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

which is known to be convergent.

The nature of a series (convergent / not convergent) being not entailed by the fact that a finite number of terms are dropped in it, our proof is completed.

---

**Remark** : using complex function theory, more precisely residue theorem, under the condition that $p(x)$ has simple roots, one can express the second series as a certain sum.

$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}=-\text{sum of values of} \ \dfrac{\pi \cot(\pi x)}{p(x)} \ \text{at roots of} \  p.$$

(see  http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf)

For example, if $p(x)=x^2+x+1$,

$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(n)}=-r(\omega)-r(\overline{\omega})= \dfrac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}} \tanh(\pi \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}),$$

where $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}$ and $\overline{\omega}$ are the roots of $p(x)=0$ and $r(x):=\dfrac{\pi \cot(\pi x)}{p'(x)}$ (classical formula for the residue at a simple pole).

Comment: If $a>0$ then don't we have, for $n$ large enough, $an^2+bn+c>0$?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: But the first inequality in your answer says the contrary. Also, I did not understand from where the $\frac{1}{2}an^2$ comes from.

Comment: I have corrected an error in the last formula (2/a instead of 1/(2a)). Is that the problem you had ?

Comment: Do you agree that if the sum of your series is $S$, you only have to divide coefficients $a,b,c$ by 2 in order to get a sum of 2S, whatever the value of $S$ ?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for your answer!